# QComboboxes in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I would like one of the cells in a table to be a QComboBox. However, I don't want them displayed as such all the time, only when a user selects that cells. Are there any more convenient ways of accomplishing this than detecting when a cell's been clicked, removing the item in the cell and replacing it with a widget, and switching it back to an item when the user's clicked away from that cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do that is to use [item delegates](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html). You install your delegates using one of the [setItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) methods of the view/widget. The delegate is responsible for display and editing of the cell, and you don't have to do the click/key handling yourself.

The documentation for this is in the model/view programming guide [delegate classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes) section (with examples).